# How to order sql server query with one to many relationship and pagination

Tags: sql-server, pagination, one-to-many

I have an sql server database full of products and each product has 1 style record and 1 or more sku records. I'm able to successfully paginate my queries on these tables using dense_rank(), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to order the styles based on a column other than the style_id and still be able to add a an incremental rank to each style.

I'm currently using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    styles.style_id
    styles.department,
    styles.style,
    styles.brand,
    styles.description,
    skus.sku_id,
    skus.color,
    skus.size,
    skus.price,
    skus.creation_date,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY styles.style_id) AS style_rank
  FROM skus
  LEFT OUTER JOIN styles ON styles.style_id=skus.style_id
  WHERE skus.color='blue'
  AND styles.brand='acme'
) AS t1
WHERE
t1.style_rank > 0 AND t1.style_rank <= 25
```

The above will allow me to paginate at the style level, but I need to be able to sort these styles based on price ASC/DESC or creation_date ASC/DESC. It would be nice to be able to control the sorting with an aggregate function like sort styles by MAX(skus.price), but that is not necessary.

To clarify, one style may have three skus and each of these three skus could be a different price.

This seems to be a pretty basic need for any retail website using RDBMS, but I cant find any documentation on how to do this.

Any suggestions on how this could be done would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I solved this using two queries (shown in my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `PARTITION BY styles.style_id` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    styles.style_id
    styles.department,
    styles.style,
    styles.brand,
    styles.description,
    skus.sku_id,
    skus.color,
    skus.size,
    skus.price,
    skus.creation_date,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY styles.style_id
                       ORDER BY skus.createion_date DESC, skus.price) AS style_rank
  FROM skus
  LEFT OUTER JOIN styles ON styles.style_id=skus.style_id
  WHERE skus.color='blue'
  AND styles.brand='acme'
) AS t1
WHERE
t1.style_rank > 0 AND t1.style_rank <= 25
```

Comment: I believe that I already tried that, but let me give it another shot.

Comment: @user1034772 - You might need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `DENSE_RANK()`.

Comment: I just tried the above with both DENSE_RANK() AND ROW_NUMBER() but both of these rank the price within the context of an individual style. I need to be able to limit the number of styles to show, but also be able to order the entire result set before ranking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution using two queries. The first query is to get the styles. The second is a "multi-get" query using the style_id's from the first query to get all of the skus.

First query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    styles.style_id
    styles.department,
    styles.style,
    styles.brand,
    styles.description,
    MAX(skus.price) AS max_price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(skus.price) DESC) AS price_rank
  FROM skus
  LEFT OUTER JOIN styles ON styles.style_id=skus.style_id
  WHERE skus.color='blue'
  AND styles.brand='acme'
  GROUP BY styles.style_id, styles.department, styles.style, styles.brand, styles.description
) AS t1
WHERE
t1.price_rank > 0 AND t1.price_rank <= 25
```

Second query:

```
SELECT
  skus.style_id,
  skus.sku_id,
  skus.color,
  skus.size,
  skus.price,
  skus.creation_date
FROM skus
WHERE skus.style_id ='styleid1' OR skus.style_id='styleid2' OR skus.style_id='styleid3' /* etc. */
```

Now populate style objects with the appropriate skus from the second query.